# "No known conversion" from const when passing "this" as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, constants

I am currently making a game which utilizes a state stack manager which keeps track of all the different game states, like the main menu.

However, I have encountered a problem which I can't seem to solve.

This is the state class, stripped down to only contain the offending code:

```c
class StateManager;

namespace first {
namespace second {

class State {
  friend class StateManager;
  protected:
    /**
     * Associates the state with the specified state manager instance.
     * @param stateManager The instance to associate this state with
     */
    void associateWithManager(StateManager *stateManager) {
      mStateManager = stateManager;
    }
  private:
    StateManager *mStateManager;
};

} // second
} // first
```

The following is the state manager, also stripped down:

```c
namespace first {
namespace second {

class StateManager {
  public:
    /**
     * Adds a state to the stack.
     * @param state The state to add
     */
    State &add(State &state) {
      state.associateWithManager(this);
      return state;
    }
};

} // second
} // first
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error (line numbers are a bit off, since I have include guards, etc.):

```
src/StateManager.cc: In member function 'State& StateManager::add(State&)':
src/StateManager.cc:7:34: error: no matching function for call to 'State::associateWithManager(StateManager* const)'
src/StateManager.cc:7:34: note: candidate is:
In file included from ./include/StateManager.h:4:0,
                 from src/StateManager.cc:1:
./include/State.h:29:10: note: void State::associateWithManager(StateManager*)
./include/State.h:29:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StateManager* const' to 'StateManager*'
```

Apparently, the `this` pointer is treated like a const pointer, even though I don't use the `const` keyword on the `add` method. I'm not sure exactly what is going on here. Is the `this` pointer always `const`? I'm pretty sure I've used it this way in the past with no problems though.

Also, is the way I'm going about this the 'correct' way? Or is there a better solution when it comes to letting the state know about the manager? Perhaps using a singleton, but I'm not really a big fan of that.

**EDIT:** I now realize that the forward declaration outside the namespaces was the reason for this. Should I accept Mike's answer, since it helped me come to this conclusion? Or should I post my own?

Comment: The code is fine as presented.  Are you forward declaring `StateManager`?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/JeS2bc). Is this really the only error?

Comment: I stripped the namespaces when I posted the question, but turns out it actually does compile without them. I'm updating the question now to show the code with namespaces and the like. @ecatmur I am indeed forward declaring StateManager.

Comment: ...but I just realized that I did it outside the namespace... I guess since Mike's answer also helped me come to this conclusion, I should accept it? Should I update the question with the actual code as well? Or maybe I should just delete this? I feel really stupid right now, I blame it on a lack of nutrition. =P

Comment: concering the edit: mike's answer did come really close. accept it and leave a comment, Id say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the only error? When I compile it, I get this error first:

```
test.cpp:8:31: error: ‘StateManager’ has not been declared
```

When declaring a class to be a friend, the class must already have been declared, otherwise the declaration is ignored. So you need to declare `class StateManager;` in the surrounding namespace before the definition of `class State`. With that change, your code compiles for me.

Comment: Your answer helped me find the actual problem, see my edit in the question. Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: @Merigrim: If you have a better answer, then go ahead and post it if you like.

Comment: While I could compose an answer that pointed out the specific problem and solved it, I do not think it is necessarily better to do so. In this situation, is that the proper thing to do, even though your answer was this close?

Comment: @Merigrim: I wouldn't worry too much either way. The important thing is that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

the `this` pointer is not a `StateManager *`, it is a `StateManager * const`

try changing the constness of your argument to `StateManager* const stateManager`

if you don't want to modifiy your calling function you can always cast away the constness:
`state.associateWithManager(const_cast<StateManager*>(this));`